# What linux kernel is arch linux using?

Tags: arch-linux

What is the version of the linux kernel that arch linux is using? Is it 3.0 or lower or higher? I couldn't find the info anywhere, I'm hoping someone else knows.

Comment: http://www.archlinux.org/news/20110819-installation-media/ < so the first article on the front page of the site didn't tell you?

Comment: also I'm closing this because as a rolling distro this is going to change very fast...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arch has an online database of all the packages in the core repositiories: you can see from that it is currently [linux 3.14-5](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/i686/linux/). (as of April 12 2014)

Answer (score 3):

From the [download](http://www.archlinux.org/download/) page on archlinux.org

> Included Kernel: 3.0.3